# How much tax to pay on award money for a minor

Tags: united-states, taxes, minor

I am a minor (16 years old) and I won $5000 from a research competition. My teacher informed me I have to pay taxes on this - is there some way to calculate how much I'd have to pay? I live in the USA.

Comment: What country?  Tax related questions require a country tag.

Comment: USA. I edited the question

Comment: If it is the only income you get this year, the tax is zero. There is a minimum income before taxes kick in, somewhere above 12k.

Comment: It's the only income I got this year but if i recall correctly, it is not earned income - it is unearned income so I think different rules may apply.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Interactive Tax Assistant](https://www.irs.gov/help/ita), you will have to file a return:

> Do I need to file a tax return?

> You are required to file a tax return for 2020. Your return's gross
> income is equal to, or exceeds, $1,100. File your return *[via paper mail, **or**]*
> electronically using one of the following four options:
>
> - Use IRS Free File (for certain low-income taxpayers) or Fillable    Forms
> - Use a Free Tax Return Preparation Site
> - Use Commercial Software
> - Find an Authorized e-File Provider

IRS is not saying you must e-file. You can always file by paper mail: download the 1040 and other relevant forms, fill them out in ink or inside your PDF viewer, print and mail.

Your parents also have to file Form 8615, [because](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i8615.pdf):

> Form 8615 must be filed for any child who meets all of the following
> conditions.
>
> 1. The child had more than $2,200 of unearned income.
> 2. The child is required to file a tax return.
> 3. through 5. (blah blah, the child is a normal dependent)

Comment: This addresses filing requirement, but doesn't answer the question of how much tax. Yes when you file you'll learn how much you owe, but it doesn't need to be a mystery up until that point.

Comment: @HartCO Without knowing the parent's top rate there's no way to compute the taxes.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Yes, they will have to disclose that to OP. I've not dealt with tax returns for dependents in a long time, but based on what I recall it looks like for 2020 OP would pay parent's top marginal rate * $2,800 + $110, those figures might be different for 2021 but that's a good starting point.

Comment: The part you quoted makes it sound like you *have to* file *electronically*.  That is not true.  IRS wrote that language at a time when most people filed on paper and so knew that, IRS is trying to *promote* e-filing by making people aware of those alternatives.  Edit submitted.

Answer (score 5):

As it doesn't seem like the award fits with [IRS Topic No. 421 Scholarships, Fellowship Grants, and Other Grants](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc421)),

Your research award will most likely be reported on a [1099-MISC](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-1099-misc). The tax paperwork like W-2 will be sent to you in late January/early February in the next tax year.

The big issue is that if you are being claimed as a **dependent** by your parents/guardians:

From: [IRS Tax Topics 551 - Dependents](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc551#:%7E:text=Dependents%20%E2%80%93%20If%20you%20can%20be,deduction%20for%20your%20filing%20status)

> **Dependents** – If you can be claimed as a dependent by another taxpayer, your **standard deduction for 2020** is limited to the greater of: (1) **$1,100**, or (2) your **earned income plus $350** (but the total can't be more than the basic standard deduction for your filing status).

Note the above stated **[earned income](https://www.irs.gov/credits-deductions/individuals/earned-income-tax-credit/earned-income-and-earned-income-tax-credit-eitc-tables#Earned%20Income)** which usually comes on a W-2 (part-time or summer job). So you won't be able to use the 'basic standard deduction' for a single taxpayer ($12,400 in 2020) if being claimed as a dependent.

As you are under 18 and made more than $2,200, [Form 8615 - Tax for Certain Children Who Have Unearned Income](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-8615) applies so how much your parents/guardians earn affects how much tax you pay.

Comment: Unearned income above 2,200 will be taxed at the parents top rate..

Comment: @HartCO Thanks. Missed that.